# How to structure database fo user notification

Tags: php, mysql, database, structure

I'm currently working on a study app and I need to create a database table to store notification for users, but therein lies the dilemma. I'm not too familiar with database structuring. I intend to have customized notification for users and also notification that will be general, that is for every user on the platform. 
I don't know how to go about it, should I create a database table for each user or a common database table for all users but specify the user id?
Thanks.

Comment: This is too broad for SO, BUT never `create a database table for each user`. Likely a table of users, table of notification types, and table of users to notification types.

Comment: Does you application require you to keep track of the delivery of messages to individual users? You would be wise to work out how messages will flow to users, both individual and broadcast. And @user3783243 is right. DEFINITELY don't design this with more than a few tables, even when it has millions of messages and users in it.

Comment: I will like to keep track of what notification goes to what user. So does this mean that I can create a table to host the notification? But this way, there might be duplicates in the table since each user would get almost the same notification but customized to include their details like username, etc. Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used model from this post: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:nFWtBYOaZiEJ:https://blog.osmosys.asia/2017/04/26/design-notification-system/+&cd=14&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=vn

I think it's useful for every notification biz model

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.